# Preventing bad data input

Tags: database, postgresql, web-applications

Is it good practice to delegate data validation entirely to the database engine constraints?

Validating data from the application doesn't prevent invalid insertion from another software (possibly written in another language by another team). Using database constraints you reduce the points where you need to worry about invalid input data.

If you put validation both in database and application, maintenance becomes boring, because you have to update code for who knows how many applications, increasing the probability of human errors.

I just don't see this being done very much, looking at code from free software projects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's best to, where possible, have your validation rules specified in your database and use or write a framework that makes those rules bubble up into your front end.  ASP.NET Dynamic Data helps with this and there are some commercial libraries out there that make it even easier.

This can be done both for simple input validation (like numbers or dates) and related data like that constrained by foreign keys.

In summary, the idea is to define the rules in one place (the database most the time) and have code in other layers that will enforce those rules.

Answer (score 11):

Validate at input time.  Validate again before you put it in the database.  And have database constraints to prevent bad input.  And you can bet in spite of all that, bad data will still get into your database, so validate it again when you use it.

It seems like every day some web app gets hacked because they did all their validation in the form or worse, using Javascript, and people found a way to bypass it.  You've got to guard against that.

Paranoid?  Me?  No, just experienced.

Answer (score 1):

The disadvantage to leaving the logic to the database is then you increase the load on that particular server.  Web and application servers are comparatively easy to scale outward, but a database requires special techniques.  As a general rule, it's a good idea to put as much of the computational logic into the application layer and keep the interaction with the database as simple as possible.

With that said, it is possible that your application may not need to worry about such heavy scalability issues.  If you are *certain* that database server load will not be a problem for the foreseeable future, then go ahead and put the constraints on the database.  You are quite correct that this improves the organization and simplicity of your system as a whole by keeping validation logic in a central location.

Answer (score 1):

There are other concerns than just SQL injection with input. You should take the most defensive stance possible whenever accepting user input. For example, a user might be able to enter a link to an image into a textbox, which is actually a PHP script that runs something nasty.

If you design your application well, you should not have to laboriously check all input. For example, you could use a Forms API which takes care of most of the work for you, and a database layer which does much the same.

This is a good resource for basic checking of vulnerabilities:

http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html

Answer (score 1):

It's far too late by the time the data gets to your database to provide meaningful validation for your users and applications.  You don't want your database doing *all* the validation since that'll slow things down pretty good, and the database doesn't express the logic as clearly.  Similarly, as you grow you'll be writing more application level transactions to complement your database transactions.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it's potentially a bad practice, depending on what happens when the query fails.  For example, if your database could throw an error that was intelligently handled by an application, then you might be ok.

On the other hand, if you don't put any validation in your app, you might not have any bad data, but you may have users thinking they entered stuff that doesn't get saved.

Answer (score 0):

Implement as much data validation as you can at the database end without compromising other goals. For example, if speed is an issue, you may want to consider *not* using foreign keys, etc. Furthermore, some data validation can only be performed on the application side, e.g., ensuring that email addresses have valid domains.

Answer (score 0):

Another disadvantage to doing data validation from the database is that often you dont validate the same way in every case. In fact, it often depends on application logic (user roles), and sometimes you might want to bypass validation altogether (cron jobs and maintenance scripts).

Answer (score 0):

I've found that doing validation in the application, rather than in the database, works well.  Of course then, all the interaction needs to go through your application.  If you have other applications that work with your data, your application will need to support some sort of API (hopefully REST).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is one right answer, it depends on your use.

If you are going to have a very heavily used system, with the potential that the database performance might become a bottleneck, then you might want to move the responsibility for validation to the front-end where it is easier to scale with multiple servers.

If you have multiple applications interacting with the database, then you might not want to replicate and maintain the validation rules across multiple applications, so then the database might be the better place.

You might want a slicker input screen that doesn't just hit the user with validation warnings when they try to save a record, maybe you want to validate a field after data has been entered and it losses focus; or even as the user types, changing the font colour as validation fails/passes.

Also related to constraints, is warnings of suspect data. In my application I have hard-constraints in the database (e.g. someone can't start a job before their date of birth), but then in the front-end have warnings for data that is possibly correct, but suspect (e.g. an eight year-old starting a job).